# Apple's U2 ads - light effects and mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, lighting-effects

How to achieve this light effect/mask in Photoshop:

[image]

[image]

I tried different shading and masking but I'm not able to achieve the look and feel of this visual.

Answer (score 2):

### Pun Intended:

[image]

---

### Layers:

[image]

▲ **Blending mode: Overlay**

[image]

▲ **Blending mode: Normal at 25%**

[image]

▲ **Blending mode: Lighten at 80%**

[image]

▲ **Blending mode: Normal**

---

**Photo credits:**

- https://www.flickr.com/photos/l_bo/2747581103
- http://mediamilitia.com/human-skulls-54-free-images/
- http://blog.mlive.com/kalamazoo_gazette_extra/2008/01/u2_members_see_their_own_perfo.html

*Note: Once you combine all the layers together you will notice that the color gradient layer (1) is covering the whole picture, to avoid this you can use the bottom layer as a transparency mask*